# Make ggplot connect datapoints in a scatterplot chronologically

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2, longitudinal

This seems very simple but for some reason I can't make it work.

I have a dataset with 3 variables. The first variable is a measurement which is taken several times per day across two months (it can take the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 - these are not groups, it is values that have been measured). The second variable are the dates. The third variable are the times the measurement was taken.  I want to plot how this measurement changes across time so I need the datapoints to be connected chronologically.

Things I have tried:

1. I have tried to plot just using date by making sure it is a date format and it is ordered correctly and then specified + geom_path() which should tell R I want it to go row by row connecting

```
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
DF <- DF[order(DF$Date),]

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date, y = Measurement)) +
     geom_line(linewidth=1, colour="green") +
     geom_path()
```

2. I created a DateTime variable:

```
DF$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(DF$Date, DF$Time, format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = DateTime, y = Measurement)) +
     geom_line(linewidth=1, colour="green")
```

In both cases R just connects all the response of value 1 to each other, all responses of value 2 to each other and so on. And does not do it chronologically.

Thank you!

```
structure(list(Measurement = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "5", "4", "5", "3", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "5", "4", "4", "5", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "4", 
"3", "3", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "4", "5", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", 
"1", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "6", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "3", "3", 
"4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", 
"3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"5", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "3", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"3", "4", "4", "5"), Date = structure(c(19333, 19333, 
19334, 19334, 19334, 19334, 19334, 19334, 19334, 19335, 19335, 
19335, 19335, 19335, 19335, 19335, 19335, 19336, 19336, 19336, 
19336, 19336, 19336, 19337, 19337, 19337, 19337, 19337, 19337, 
19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19338, 
19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 19339, 
19340, 19340, 19340, 19340, 19341, 19341, 19341, 19341, 19342, 
19342, 19342, 19342, 19342, 19342, 19342, 19343, 19343, 19343, 
19343, 19343, 19344, 19344, 19344, 19344, 19344, 19345, 19345, 
19345, 19345, 19346, 19346, 19346, 19346, 19347, 19347, 19347, 
19347, 19348, 19348, 19349, 19350, 19350, 19350, 19350, 19350, 
19350, 19351, 19351, 19351, 19352, 19353, 19353, 19353, 19353, 
19353, 19354, 19355, 19355, 19355, 19356, 19356, 19356, 19356, 
19357, 19357, 19357, 19357, 19358, 19358, 19358, 19358, 19359, 
19359, 19359, 19359, 19360, 19360, 19360, 19360, 19360, 19361, 
19361, 19362, 19362, 19362, 19362, 19363, 19363, 19363, 19363, 
19364, 19364, 19364, 19364, 19364, 19365, 19365, 19365, 19365, 
19365, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19367, 19367, 19367, 
19367, 19367, 19368, 19368, 19368, 19368, 19369, 19369, 19369, 
19370, 19370, 19370, 19371, 19371, 19371, 19372, 19372, 19372, 
19372, 19372, 19373, 19373, 19373, 19373, 19374, 19374, 19374, 
19374, 19374, 19374, 19375, 19375, 19375, 19375, 19376, 19376, 
19376, 19377, 19377, 19377, 19377, 19377, 19378, 19378, 19378, 
19378, 19379, 19379, 19379, 19379, 19379, 19380, 19380, 19380, 
19380, 19380, 19381, 19381, 19381, 19381, 19382, 19382, 19382, 
19382, 19383, 19383, 19385, 19385, 19385, 19385, 19385, 19385, 
19385, 19385, 19385, 19385, 19386, 19386, 19386, 19386, 19386, 
19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 19387, 
19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 19388, 
19389, 19389, 19389, 19389, 19389, 19389, 19389, 19389, 19390, 
19390, 19390, 19390, 19390, 19390, 19390, 19390, 19390), class = "Date"), 
    Time = structure(c(43810, 44174, 49104, 49343, 50921, 
    54029, 59443, 65767, 70544, 40647, 40731, 43219, 50506, 54044, 
    58687, 68571, 71016, 36049, 38921, 44148, 55413, 66503, 70310, 
    34796, 48468, 48770, 56701, 67069, 73131, 32103, 37937, 43270, 
    43941, 49507, 57796, 59420, 65187, 70669, 28787, 33612, 38807, 
    43900, 49607, 54026, 60525, 65861, 76855, 29833, 43197, 45349, 
    67928, 34018, 44887, 54024, 65491, 34687, 45029, 45029, 45096, 
    45096, 56881, 70503, 30726, 49625, 54871, 76945, 76990, 30348, 
    51899, 58286, 65893, 76301, 34075, 54033, 54075, 66322, 34158, 
    47973, 69070, 69113, 29971, 43838, 43891, 68344, 58512, 64840, 
    74134, 42286, 48249, 53712, 75669, 75669, 75669, 34484, 67922, 
    67922, 63298, 30761, 30814, 52835, 67936, 78132, 69679, 44485, 
    61309, 65893, 32443, 46595, 55031, 65701, 40995, 43257, 78737, 
    78783, 35103, 58260, 65353, 78583, 36651, 44588, 53857, 74257, 
    34262, 44172, 50954, 56508, 68744, 32577, 54241, 32233, 45405, 
    59002, 68596, 33529, 44235, 56676, 65104, 35378, 43263, 59195, 
    70423, 76305, 34704, 40350, 43769, 54069, 65163, 32335, 43220, 
    52463, 64829, 64883, 33312, 47326, 56974, 78210, 78249, 37710, 
    47664, 51668, 67281, 39815, 57103, 67451, 52368, 54111, 66853, 
    45038, 45079, 64861, 35856, 45970, 54136, 54174, 67102, 32497, 
    49309, 56959, 68312, 33326, 44280, 53945, 54763, 65275, 65313, 
    32958, 52099, 57512, 65378, 27223, 58171, 64993, 32862, 44507, 
    44547, 54631, 76109, 33983, 49720, 58810, 66231, 29886, 53075, 
    54592, 64904, 64942, 29982, 40303, 43288, 54319, 65762, 28881, 
    36993, 44716, 65239, 34587, 43395, 64886, 66650, 41670, 53480, 
    29252, 38412, 38477, 38477, 44963, 48648, 56521, 59572, 65410, 
    70232, 32517, 38681, 43273, 50715, 74179, 33337, 39419, 39419, 
    40341, 49560, 59123, 60091, 65164, 70217, 37318, 37822, 43242, 
    43287, 49346, 55187, 59908, 64815, 72710, 32553, 33678, 37864, 
    43283, 54029, 59412, 68693, 78965, 34730, 38193, 43936, 51483, 
    54039, 54134, 59417, 66687, 72937), class = c("hms", "difftime"
    ), units = "secs"), DateTime = structure(c(1670415010, 1670415374, 
    1670506704, 1670506943, 1670508521, 1670511629, 1670517043, 
    1670523367, 1670528144, 1670584647, 1670584731, 1670587219, 
    1670594506, 1670598044, 1670602687, 1670612571, 1670615016, 
    1670666449, 1670669321, 1670674548, 1670685813, 1670696903, 
    1670700710, 1670751596, 1670765268, 1670765570, 1670773501, 
    1670783869, 1670789931, 1670835303, 1670841137, 1670846470, 
    1670847141, 1670852707, 1670860996, 1670862620, 1670868387, 
    1670873869, 1670918387, 1670923212, 1670928407, 1670933500, 
    1670939207, 1670943626, 1670950125, 1670955461, 1670966455, 
    1671005833, 1671019197, 1671021349, 1671043928, 1671096418, 
    1671107287, 1671116424, 1671127891, 1671183487, 1671193829, 
    1671193829, 1671193896, 1671193896, 1671205681, 1671219303, 
    1671265926, 1671284825, 1671290071, 1671312145, 1671312190, 
    1671351948, 1671373499, 1671379886, 1671387493, 1671397901, 
    1671442075, 1671462033, 1671462075, 1671474322, 1671528558, 
    1671542373, 1671563470, 1671563513, 1671610771, 1671624638, 
    1671624691, 1671649144, 1671725712, 1671732040, 1671827734, 
    1671882286, 1671888249, 1671893712, 1671915669, 1671915669, 
    1671915669, 1671960884, 1671994322, 1671994322, 1672076098, 
    1672129961, 1672130014, 1672152035, 1672167136, 1672177332, 
    1672255279, 1672316485, 1672333309, 1672337893, 1672390843, 
    1672404995, 1672413431, 1672424101, 1672485795, 1672488057, 
    1672523537, 1672523583, 1672566303, 1672589460, 1672596553, 
    1672609783, 1672654251, 1672662188, 1672671457, 1672691857, 
    1672738262, 1672748172, 1672754954, 1672760508, 1672772744, 
    1672822977, 1672844641, 1672909033, 1672922205, 1672935802, 
    1672945396, 1672996729, 1673007435, 1673019876, 1673028304, 
    1673084978, 1673092863, 1673108795, 1673120023, 1673125905, 
    1673170704, 1673176350, 1673179769, 1673190069, 1673201163, 
    1673254735, 1673265620, 1673274863, 1673287229, 1673287283, 
    1673342112, 1673356126, 1673365774, 1673387010, 1673387049, 
    1673432910, 1673442864, 1673446868, 1673462481, 1673521415, 
    1673538703, 1673549051, 1673620368, 1673622111, 1673634853, 
    1673699438, 1673699479, 1673719261, 1673776656, 1673786770, 
    1673794936, 1673794974, 1673807902, 1673859697, 1673876509, 
    1673884159, 1673895512, 1673946926, 1673957880, 1673967545, 
    1673968363, 1673978875, 1673978913, 1674032958, 1674052099, 
    1674057512, 1674065378, 1674113623, 1674144571, 1674151393, 
    1674205662, 1674217307, 1674217347, 1674227431, 1674248909, 
    1674293183, 1674308920, 1674318010, 1674325431, 1674375486, 
    1674398675, 1674400192, 1674410504, 1674410542, 1674461982, 
    1674472303, 1674475288, 1674486319, 1674497762, 1674547281, 
    1674555393, 1674563116, 1674583639, 1674639387, 1674648195, 
    1674669686, 1674671450, 1674732870, 1674744680, 1674893252, 
    1674902412, 1674902477, 1674902477, 1674908963, 1674912648, 
    1674920521, 1674923572, 1674929410, 1674934232, 1674982917, 
    1674989081, 1674993673, 1675001115, 1675024579, 1675070137, 
    1675076219, 1675076219, 1675077141, 1675086360, 1675095923, 
    1675096891, 1675101964, 1675107017, 1675160518, 1675161022, 
    1675166442, 1675166487, 1675172546, 1675178387, 1675183108, 
    1675188015, 1675195910, 1675242153, 1675243278, 1675247464, 
    1675252883, 1675263629, 1675269012, 1675278293, 1675288565, 
    1675330730, 1675334193, 1675339936, 1675347483, 1675350039, 
    1675350134, 1675355417, 1675362687, 1675368937), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -271L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hey, can you `dput()` the sample data it would help a lot.

Comment: Hello, just did that. Thank you!

Comment: When you say that you want to plot how the measurement changes across **time**, do you mean the date or the exact time and date? You have a lot of datetime values, so it may be difficult to visualize information about the time of day when the measurement was taken.

Comment: Hello, both date and time, this is why I created the DateTime variable. Basically, like a time series. Each datapoint has a corresponding date and time. I don't need to show the time on the x axis but I would show a few dates (maybe at 10-15 day intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the points chronologically by specifying [`group = 1`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html). Additionally, you can use [`scale_x_datetime`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) to control the breaks on your x-axis. For the way the x-axis is labelled, see [this r-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/date-formats-in-r/#:%7E:text=a%20gist.-,Date%20Formats,-Conversion%20specification) for more information about date formats.

I've included one example that best recreates what you were trying to do and another example where the points are colored by `Measurement`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date) 
DF <- DF[order(DF$Date),]
DF$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(DF$Date, DF$Time, format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))

# what I think you want
ggplot(DF, aes(x = DateTime, y = Measurement, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, color = "green") + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "10 days", date_labels = "%b %d %y")

# another option
ggplot(DF, aes(x = DateTime, y = Measurement, color = Measurement, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, color = "gray") + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "10 days", date_labels = "%b %d %y")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, Measurement is not a dummy variable indicating group. It is what I measure (mood) and it takes the values 1, 2, 3,4,5,6.

Comment: Are the points in the first or second plot above not correctly connected?

Comment: Hello it worked, thank you. I don't understand why it worked but it did!